# Field, attachment Encryption

Tags: attachment

Does Salesforce support encryption of attachments (does it automatically encrypt attachments), if not could it be implemented? If so how?

Does Salesforce supports Encryption of Types other than Text (I need to encrypt a Number/Currency Field)?

Salesforce supports only 128 bit encryption (Text (Encrypted) Type), could 256 bit encryption be enforced?

Does Salesforce Support Database Encryption (encrypting the entire DB)?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Crypto_Class

There are crypto classes that can help you in achieving the encryption and decryption.

Apart from the encrypted fields as you saw if you want sophisticated encryption of data for your org there is an excellent app

http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003JVUnEAO

CipherCloud for Salesforce is a cloud encryption gateway that resides within your network to secure sensitive customer data in real-time while retaining all of the native Salesforce, Force.com, and Chatter functionality that your end users love.

Comment: Thanks Mohith, using Crypto class requires customization ... the steps I should follow is as below:                              [1] Develop a Custom VF page to Input the Restricted data      [2] Create AES256 Key and Encrypt the data                  [3] Use APEX to insert the data into a normal Field (Say text/currency)

Answer (score 0):

[Platform Encryption](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_pe_overview.htm), a new product for native encryption provided by salesforce, supports encrypting attachments with AES-256.